# change mandrill template dynamically using php

Tags: php, mandrill

I am using mandrill app to send emails from my website.
I know how to send template using Mandrill.

I want to change template dynamically. I don't know how to do it.
On this [Site](http://help.mandrill.com/entries/21678522-How-do-I-use-merge-tags-to-add-dynamic-content-) they mentioned to use *|---|* to change template dynamically. Here they aso mentioned how to declare global merge vars in JSON code.

My question is how to define global merge vars in PHP code?

Answer (score 0):

Probably I misunderstood your question, but here is my answer:
I assume that you are using [mandrill php library](https://packagist.org/packages/mandrill/mandrill)
Then

```
require 'Mandrill.php';
$mandrill = new Mandrill($password);
$message = array(
     'html' => $html //here you can provide your html for template
     //receiver and so on
);
$mandrill->messages->send($message);
```

Comment: Hey thanks I got answer to may question. I wanted to ask how to replace text in template using mandrill PHP.